# How to combine SQL OR conditions in Product Collection ? Magento?

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.9

I want my results to come either from `name` match **OR** `description` match.

```
$custom_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('type')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array('attribute' => 'name', 'like' => '%' . $queryText . '%'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array('attribute' => 'description', 'like' => '%' . $queryText . '%'))
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', array(11, 4));
```

These are the two specific lines I need to merge

```
->addAttributeToFilter(array('attribute' => 'name', 'like' => '%' . $queryText . '%'))
->addAttributeToFilter(array('attribute' => 'description', 'like' => '%' . $queryText . '%'))
```

Comment: you can use this way WHERE ((name LIKE 'value') OR (description LIKE 'value') OR (anotherattribute LIKE 'value')).....Refer this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7908/multi-conditionals-or-and-and-inside-and-in-addattributetofilter

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for OR condition.

```
 $custom_collection->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute'=> 'name','like' => '%' . $queryText . '%'),
            array('attribute'=> 'description','like' => '%' . $queryText . '%')
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
array(
    array('attribute'=> 'name','like' => ''%' . $queryText . '%''),
    array('attribute'=> 'description','like' => ''%' . $queryText . '%''),
    )
);
```

This will output a WHERE clause of the format:

```
 WHERE ((name LIKE ''%' . $queryText . '%'') OR (description LIKE ''%' . $queryText . '%'')
```